# go -mux, why the route doesn't resolve?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, mux

I'm trying to deploy my first golang app on GAE. For some reasons the products handler doesn't resolve and I get 404 errors. Am I missing something ?

```
package test
import "github.com/gorilla/mux"
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)



func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/products", ProductsHandler)
    http.Handle("/", r)

       e := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
    if e != nil {
      println(e.Error())
    }
}

func ProductsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, you!")
}
```

Comment: `ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)` - see http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go on AppEngine will automatically listen on the correct port and serve the `http.DefaultServeMux`.  Change your `main` function to an `init` and remove the serve logic and you should be all set.

Read through the [Getting Started section on Requests and HTTP](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/#Go_Requests_and_HTTP) for more detail.

Comment: Yeah, call http.HandleFunc in an init() method instead of main and remove the main entirely. App Engine takes care of the main method.

Comment: May I ask what's the reason to use init instead of main ? J